# How can I make Linux chain through 2 VPN connections?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, tunnel

I am looking to setup a WiFi access point for use in my Uni halls, except I have a problem and that is my uni require the use of a VPN. And I would like to mask my traffic by using another VPN. I'm going to use Linux for this, and I am fairly confident with Linux.

Basically, my packets should flow something like this:

[image: Flowchart]

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I assume it's possible to do this somehow.

Comment: Did you succeed with this? How does it go if you simply put a VPN server on the access point / router (e.g. with DD-WRT) and connect to the UNI VPN after already connected to External? Why couldn't you wrap one VPN package into another one?

Comment: @László I managed to connect to the Uni VPN on the Pi, and then the external one from my laptop and it worked okay

Comment: @László Raspberry Pi